# C# Function that can return either of two different page objects

Tags: c#, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver, return-value

I have a function that returns a `WelcomeScreen` page object as follows:

```
public WelcomeScreen UpdateAndSubmitProfile()
{
    LastNameField.Clear();
    LastNameField.SendKeys("Malik");
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Update Last Name profile field, Last Name => Malik");
    ProfileSubmitButton.Click();
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Click Submit button.");
    return new WelcomeScreen(Driver);
}
```

Now, I want to access this same method but would like it to return another page object `LessonPage` (`return new LessonPage(Driver)`). Is there any way to accomplish this using the same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private method with the logic and warp it with two methods, each return a page object

```
private void UpdateAndSubmitProfile()
{
    LastNameField.Clear();
    LastNameField.SendKeys("Malik");
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Update Last Name profile field, Last Name => Malik");
    ProfileSubmitButton.Click();
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Click Submit button.");
}

public WelcomeScreen UpdateAndSubmitProfileAndGoToWelcomeScreen()
{
    UpdateAndSubmitProfile();
    return new WelcomeScreen(Driver);
}

public LessonPage UpdateAndSubmitProfileAndGoToLessonPage()
{
    UpdateAndSubmitProfile();
    return new LessonPage(Driver);
}
```

Comment: yes, I have used this technique in another place but is there any other better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @melleck IMHO this is the best way, and this is how I work. You can return parent class/interface, but if you need a method declared in the derived class you will have to cast the returned object.

Answer (score 4):

Well if both Classes implement one interface you can change the return type of the Method to the Interface.

```
public Screen UpdateAndSubmitProfile()
{
    LastNameField.Clear();
    LastNameField.SendKeys("Malik");
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Update Last Name profile field, Last Name => Malik");
    ProfileSubmitButton.Click();
    Reporter.LogPassingTestStepToBugLogger("Click Submit button.");
    if(...)
        return new WelcomeScreen(Driver);
    else
        return new LessonPage(Driver);
}
```

Comment: Both classes extend from a BaseApplicationPage class.

Comment: then you can use the base application class as well. but pulling the base class out into a interface and have them implement the interface would be best imo

Comment: You could also pass in a parameter to `UpdateAndSubmitProfile()` that controls that `if` flow to let the method know where you intend to end up and control the return that way.